# How to diagnose the SMC?

Tags: power-management, macos

This article from the Apple Knowledge Base:
[Reset the System Management Controller (SMC) on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

describes very well which kinds of events are symptoms which might
be related to an SMC in need of a reset. But the relationship isn't
clearly established.

Is there any simple method to diagnose clearly the SMC state:

- is it OK?
- does it need a reset?

Something like (for NVRAM):

```
nvram -p
```

or

```
nvram -p | diff /etc/nvram.backup -
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to go through Apple's diagnotic utilities, but be prepared for it to tell you everything is fine.

Put you machine on a flat stable surface and plug it in.  Perform a restart or a power on and immediately hold down the 'd' key (d for diagnostics).  It should at least test your power adapter which is goverened by the SMC chip.